# Permutations of a sequence of words

Tags: statistics, permutations, combinations

I've been given a question in class and I just wanted to confirm the answer

```
1) How many 3 letter sequences are possible that use the letters m, a, t, h, s at most once each?
```

For this question I know to use permutations as the order is sensitive as we are dealing with sequences so I did this:  3! or P(3,3) andre of my got 6.

The condition that states "at most once each" is throwing me off a bit and I am unsure of my answer.

So is this correct? if not how would I solve this question?

Comment: 5 choices for the first letter, 4 for the second, 3 for the third... so?

Comment: "At most once each" means "use one or none", that is: "select without repetition".

Answer (score 0):

$\mathrm{P}(\mathbf{3},3)$ or $\,^\mathbf{3}\mathrm{P}_3$ means: Count the distinct ordered sequences by selecting *without repetition* 3 symbols from a set of **3** distinct symbols.  That is $\frac{\mathbf{3}!}{(\mathbf{3}-3)!}$

However, you wish to do so from a set of **5**, so...